# Installing Wifi Card Driver on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, wireless

I'm relatively new to linux/ubuntu and I'm having troubles installing my wifi card driver for my laptop (Lenovo Legion Y520). I'm running ubuntu 16.04.

I ran some commands I found on my research. I'm currently connected with an ethernet cable.

```
~$ lspci -vnn | grep Network
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fd] (rev 78)

~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

~$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

when i go to additional drivers it shows an NVIDIA Driver for my graphics card and an unknown driver

```
Using Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs from intel-microcode (proprietary)
```

I have installed them both.

But there is no wifi card driver...

Do you have any suggestions what i could try?

Answer (score 1):

Means not supported with default kernel.

Try:

DESKTOP
 sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04

SERVER
 sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04

From: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: I ran the command and after that I ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. while the upgrade command was running it asked me to disable secure boot so I pressed ok. There was still no wifi driver available. After a reboot I got stuck in something called "BuysBox" and it wouldn't let me boot into ubuntu I really didn't know what to do so I ended up reinstalling ubuntu. I don't know what all that means have I made a mistake? Or should I just run your command again?

Comment: The only difference I noticed is that `rfkill list` results now in  0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no